# Usage of torch.scatter() for multi-dimensional value

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

i have a question regarding the usage of the torch.scatter() function.

I want to construct a weights matrix weights (# [B, N, V]. B is batch size, N is number of points and V is the number of features for each point. )

Let's say i have two tensors

```
a = # shape [B, N, k], where B is batch size, N is number of points, k is the index number within [0,V] to select feature.
b = # shape [B, N, k], where B is batch size, N is number of points, k stores here the weights for selected feature.
```

I tried to use function torch.scatter():
weights.scatter_(index=a, dim=2, value=some_fix_value). By this operation i can only set one fixed value, but not the whole value tensor b, which contains all information at those location.

Can someone gives me a hint on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking to do is:

```
weights.scatter_(dim=2, index=a, src=b)
```

In other words, `a`'s last dimension is indexing `b`'s last dimension. Which corresponds to the following operation in pseudo-code when [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_)'s `dim` argument is set to `2`:

```
out[i][j][a[i][j][k]] = b[i][j][k]
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed i use the wrong argument of .scatter() function. Using your solution resolves the issue!